# Degree of a field extension by a transcendental element

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, cardinals, transcendental-numbers

Let $F$ be a field, and let $F(x)$ be the field of fractions of the polynomial ring $F[x]$. I'm interested in the degree of the field extension $[F(x) : F]$. Obviously it is infinite, but what exactly is its cardinality? Is it $\aleph_0$? Does it depend on the field $F$?

Comment: **Hint:** Yes, it depends on the size of $F$.  Show the set $\{ 1/(x+a) \mid a\in F \}$ is linearly independent over $F$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The natural $F$-basis of $F(x)$ is $$\{ x^k, k\ge 0\} \cup \{ x^l/h^m, m\ge 1,l<\deg(h), h \in F[x]\text{ monic irreducible}\}$$
Thus (for $F$ infinite) the cardinality of the basis is comprised between that of $F$ and $F[x]^2$, ie. it is the same as $F$.

Comment: $h$ should also be normalized to avoid scalar multiples.

Comment: Technically this isn't a "basis", because (for instance) if $h = x$, $1/(x+1)$ cannot be written as a **finite** linear combination of $1/x^m$ for $m \geq 1$.

Comment: @RiversMcForge $x+1$ is irreducible, and hence $h=x+1$ is one of the alternative values. So $1/(x+1)$ is included in the basis. To get a basis reuns includes **all** monic irreducibles as $h$.

Comment: I took their response to mean that any particular $h$ which was monic and irreducible could generate the basis, but I see why you read it differently.

Comment: @RiversMcForge That it is a basis is the theorem of partial fraction decomposition

Comment: Oops people upvoted without reading carefully

Comment: @reuns Lol, I know about partial fractions. I didn't realize you meant *every* monic irreducible $h \in F[x]$ from the way that you wrote your basis.

Answer (score 0):

For any infinite field $F$, $F[x] = \oplus_{n \geq 0} F (x^n)$ is of equal cardinality to $F$, and there is a surjective mapping $F[x] \times (F[x])^* \rightarrow F(x)$ given by $(p(x), q(x)) \mapsto \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ (where $(F[x])^* = F[x] \setminus \{ 0 \}$). Since $F[x] \times (F[x])^*$ is of equal cardinality to $F[x]$, the result follows.

If $F$ is finite, $F[x]$ is countably infinite, and by the same logic as above, $F(x)$ is countably infinite as well.